# OpenVPN Copy Server Certificate/Keys Onto Different Server

Tags: openvpn, centos7, certificate, certificate-authority, keys

Let's say on `Server 1` I setup all `OpenVPN` server credentials, certificate authority, etc...

All these files have been generated on `Server 1` using the following commands:

```
./easyrsa build-ca //create ca
./easyrsa gen-dh //create diffie-hellman key
./easyrsa gen-req server nopass //create server key pair
./easyrsa sign-req server server //sign server key pair
openvpn --genkey --secret pfs.key //create perfect forward secrecy key file
```

`Server 1` `OpenVPN` server configuration file looks like this:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append openvpn.log
verb 3
tls-server
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/server/pfs.key
```

Then if I wanted to create a client key pair so a client can connect to the `OpenVPN` server on `Server 1` I would run the commands below in `Server 1`:

```
./easyrsa gen-req client nopass //create client key pair
./easyrsa sign-req client client //sign client key pair
```

Now this works fine, If I give a client the client key pair I have generated and signed on `Server 1` they can connect to the `OpenVPN` server on `Server 1` perfectly.

But let's say I wanted to create a new `OpenVPN` server (on `Server 2`) and I want the client to still be able to use the same client key pair (that I generated/signed on `Server 1`) to connect to the `OpenVPN` server hosted on `Server 2`.

I was able to get this working by simply copying/transferring the server credentials, certificate authority, etc... that I generated on `Server 1` over to `Server 2`, (I took the `ca.crt`, `server.crt`, `server.key`, `dh.pem`, `pfs.key` files I generated on `Server 1` and transferred them to `Server 2` so that `Server 2` will allow the same client key pairs I generated on `Server 1` to connect to `Server 2`) so basically `Server 2` `OpenVPN` server configuration file uses the same server credentials, certificate authority, etc... that I generated on `Server 1`.

So even though this seems to work fine, I just wanted to ensure this was the proper way to achieve what I'm going after? Is this approach safe? Is there possibly a easier/faster way to do this?

Comment: Don't forget the rest of the easy-rsa files, like CRL, index, serial, (vars), etc. Easy-rsa is file-based in its own directory only (per default), so yours is the "right" and easiest way. Just copy the easy-rsa root-folder to the new machine, I can't think of any _easier_ way.

Answer (score 2):

Easy-RSA is a (easy) way of generating the certificates, keys, etc. necessary for operating services such as OpenVPN, but also Apache/nginx. It does not matter where you run the actual program, as these files are not dependent on the computer you generated them on.

You have identified the easiest and fastest way of working with these files, which is to simply copy them. Additionally, user Lenniey suggests copying the easy-rsa root-folder to the second OpenVPN server, which is a good idea.